# Dereferencing a member pointer error: cannot be used as member pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dereference

I've got the following (truncated) class declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class btree 
{
    public:

        btree(const btree<T>& original); //This is btree's copy constructor

    private:

        struct btree_node 
        {
            btree_node(const btree_node &other)
            {
                //This is node's copy constructor
            }
        }

        btree_node* headNode;
}
```

And btree's copy constructor is implemented this way:

```
template <typename T> 
btree<T>::btree(const btree<T>& original)
{
    headNode = new btree_node(original.*headNode);
}
```

**original.*headNode** is supposed to return btree_node that original.headNode is pointing to, thus matching btree_node's copy constructor arguments.

However I get the following error:

> error: '((btree*)this)->btree::headNode' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'btree::btree_node*'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) you will see that first the `.` operator is evaluated and then the `*` (dereference) operator is evaluated.

`*` takes a pointer as argument. If you write `original.*headNode`, it's meaningless. Somehow you are telling it to get the member `*headNode` of `original`, but `*headNode` is not a member of `original`. You are also telling it to evaluate `*headNode` which is actually `*this->headNode` (note that `->` is evaluated first).

What you want is to first get the pointer by writing `original.headNode`, then dereference it by using `*`. Therefore

```
*original.headNode
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
headNode = new btree_node(*(original.headNode))
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you want is actually

```
headNode = new btree_node( *original.headNode );
```

Comment: Yep that is indeed what I wanted! Silly mistake. thanks! I thought that if I did *original.headNode then it would dereference original which is not a pointer and thus wouldn't make sense